# Display user profile field in frontend for manually created users by admin using ACF plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a plugin that creates a shortcode for displaying user profile data in the frontend. I needed to add extra data which I made possible thanks to ACF plugin. I have been able to follow how-tos and the ACF fields now display in the frontend. This is where I am losing it.

When I view the page that displays the profile e.g example.com/profile/user, my code instead checks fields for the currently logged-in user instead of the user that I am looking at.

I cannot use get_the_author_meta() because I am manually creating the users so using that checks back for the author and instead of returning the original author it returns mine (which is how it's meant to work anyways).

Example of how I am fetching data
`get_user_meta( $current_user->user_login, 'specialty', true )`
`specialty` is the name of my custom field which I have added for user.

How can I fetch the intended username of the user I just created?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the user?

Comment: I am creating a user using the Add New User option in WordPress.

Comment: Can you show that function here as well?  You should be able to return the new user id when you create user.